# WearOS onGenericMotionListener not called

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am trying to catch the action when I rotate my bezel on my Samsung Galaxy Watch 4, but it never "runs".

Here is my code:

```
findViewById(R.id.Badtunna).setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            System.out.println("GUM");
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL &&
            motionEvent.isFromSource(InputDeviceCompat.SOURCE_ROTARY_ENCODER)) {
                System.out.println("BUBBEL");

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

My view is a normal TextView:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/Badtunna"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Badtunna" />
```

Here is my onCreate() in MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // Add all the domoticz devices
    domoticz_devices.put(766, "idx_766");
    domoticz_devices.put(17, "idx_17");

    findViewById(R.id.Skymningssensor).requestFocus();

    findViewById(R.id.Skymningssensor).setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            System.out.println("GUM");
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL &&
                    motionEvent.isFromSource(InputDeviceCompat.SOURCE_ROTARY_ENCODER)) {
                System.out.println("BUBBEL");

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    TextView idx_17_button = findViewById(R.id.idx_17);
    idx_17_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                toggleDomoticzDevice(17, "idx_17");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    TextView idx_657_button = findViewById(R.id.idx_657);
    idx_657_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                toggleDomoticzDevice(657, "idx_657");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Integer i : domoticz_devices.keySet()) {
                getDomoticzDeviceAndSetTextview(i, domoticz_devices.get(i));
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

When focus is "working" should the keyboard pop up?
I have also updated my TextView and added focusable:true and focusableintouchmode:true

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: did you manage to get this working? I have added focusable = FOCUSABLE and called requestFocus() (multiple times) but no events are reported by the GenericMotionListener when attached to a TextView (works perfectly when linked to a separate RecyclerView)

Answer (score 2):

Docs here

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/rotary-input#custom-scrolling

Likely issue is focus

> Remember to make sure your view gains focus, otherwise the events will not come through.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/rotary-input#custom-scrolling

> By default, launching an activity or even tapping on a view does not give it focus, even if it is focusable. To give your view focus, the view must use the  tag or manually call View.requestFocus().

Comment: I have now updated the main post :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you are going to use for `Recyclerview`.

Add the following attribute to your `recyclerview` XML tag.

```xml
focusable="true"
focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

use below in code in Java or kotlin class

recyclerView.requestFocus()

recyclerView.requestFocusFromTouch()

Then try `setOnGenericMotionListener`, and it will work.